# How to validate one to many relationship in cakephp 3

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to validate hasMany form data.

Eg:
table order has many order_item.

I try to validate in order table's validationDefault function:

```
$validator
            ->notEmpty('cust_name')
            ->notEmpty('cust_email')
            ->notEmpty('order_items.*.oi_item');
            ->notEmpty('order_items.*.oi_price');
```

How can I validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Associations should get validated, when an entity with associated entities is passed into the Tables `save()`. So you should put your validation rules for order_item into OrderItemTable, like

```
    $validator
       ->notEmpty('oi_price')
       ->notEmpty('oi_price')
```

Whenever a validation fails you should be able to get the the error with `$order->getErrors()` (assuming that `$order` is the order entity passed to `OrdersTable::save()`).

Comment: Can I validate it without creating another model? Does cakephp support multidimensional array validation?

Comment: No I don't think so. And I couldn't think of a case why you should do that. Just bake the OrderItem Table, configure your validation rules and your good to go.

Comment: how can I use different class name because OrderItem will have different validation. The table is just for example I have different use case.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? You want to have different validators? Or are you talking about the classname of the table?